# Select drop down menu and select especific option

Tags: javascript, html

I want to click on button S and change only select elements with the same id to option value = 1.

If I clic on first Button S, only "select A1,A2 and A3" will be changed to option value 1
If I clic on second Button S, only "select B1,B2 and B3" will be changed to option value 1

I came up with this code, but I cant get it work.

```
<script>
function selec_all(bu) {
var elements, i=0;
while(elements=document.getElementById(bu.id +(i++)))  elements[i].selectedIndex = 2;
}
</script>
<form>
<div>
<input value="S" onclick="selec_all(this)" type="button" id="13887824">
<select name="A1" id="13887824">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<select name="A2" id="13887824">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<select name="A3" id="13887824">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
<input value="S" onclick="selec_all(this)" type="button" id="13887824">
<select name="B1" id="13887824">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<select name="B2" id="13887824">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<select name="B3" id="13887824">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: duplicating the id is not a good habit so use class instead because there is no method like getElementsById for multiple ids and neither valid too

Comment: you need to make a difference between IDs and Classes